# A question regarding present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-continuous

I have been devouring information for the past three months.

I have read that perfect tenses should not be used in sentenced with adverbs or adverb phrases of past time. Is the sentence mentioned above incorrect?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence.

Comment: But it's talks about the past. The subject had been devouring information for 3 months and this action ended at some time in the past.

Comment: The sentence says nothing at all about whether or not the action has actually stopped. It could easily *not* have stopped; in fact, it's more commonly used when something *hasn't* stopped—that would be the default interpretation. If you want to communicate it has having stopped, simply use *I **was** …* Or *I **had been** … when [something happened].*

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct - it is clear and unambiguous. "The past three months" is a noun phrase describing the three months that end now. The devouring is therefore very likely to have taken place in those months right up to the present.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct.
'I have been devouring information for the past three months.'
for the past three months = for the three months until now.

We can also say, 'I have been devouring information for the **last** three months'.

It has been raining for the past/last two days. for the past/last two days= for the two days until now.

Comment: Do not use Stack Exchange posts to advertise your website. This is spam, and will be treated as such.